# rsync except "last" file

Tags: linux, debian, rsync, scp

I have a `Linux` server with log rotation for every 10MB.
I would like to either `scp` or `rsync` all finished files to a remote storage.

Is it possible to `rsync` except the newest file on an ongoing basis, so `rsync` will happen as soon as a new log file is rotated?

My filenaming is ex.:

```
trace_00003_20190207134624.pcap
trace_00004_20190207144533.pcap
trace_00005_20190207154446.pcap
```

So in this case `trace_00005_20190207154446.pcap` would be actively written to and should not be caught by `rsync`.

Answer (score 1):

I would experiment with `find` and see if you could leave files alone which are newer than 15 minutes or something. eg:

```
# only rsync files older than 15 minutes
rsync -av $(find /var/pcap_dir/ -type f -mmin +15 | xargs) /tmp/dest/
```

I do recall running into a limit on the number of files `xargs` can process in one shot so you may want to look that up. It was well into the thousands IIRC so for a handful, you should be fine.  Also, whitespace or shell meta characters in your filenames will probably bollocks things up so be sure to work with shell-safe filenames.

EDIT: or just transfer a script over (untested)

```
#!/bin/bash
# myscript.sh find files 15 minutes old, or older. tar them up with bzip2 compression
find /var/pcap_dir/ -type f -mmin +15 | xargs tar cfj /tmp/results.tbz --files-from -
```

then run the script remotely to pull the tarball over to the local machine:

```
scp myscript.sh remotehost:/tmp/
ssh remotehost "/tmp/myscript.sh"
scp remotehost:/tmp/results.tbz /tmp/
ssh remotehost "rm -f /tmp/results.tbz"
```

Comment: Is this possible with remote server, so using `$(find ...)` together with `username@remote-ip:/` ?

Comment: It can be tricky running remote shell commands this way due to escaping the meta characters correctly but it can be done.  Sometimes it's easier to just `scp` a shell script to the remote, run the script remotely, and then `scp` the results back.

Answer (score 1):

If you can change the name of the log original file you can do this quite easily. I'm assuming that you use logrotate to rotate the log files.

1. Configure your application to save the log file with a different ending, for example `.pcap.current`
2. Configure logrotate to rename the file to `.pcap` upon rotation
3. rsync only files ending in `.pcap`

No need for any tricks with find or other filters.

Comment: Ah, this is a much better solution. I missed the part about `logrotate` being involved.

Answer (score 0):

You question is slightly ambiguous. I'll explain:
Option 1: backup all files with a size greater than or equal to 10MB.
Option 2: backup all files *except* the one with the latest time stamp.

I will assume you mean option 1:
Option 1 answer.  
You can use the *find* command to grab each file greater than 10MB and send that file to the *scp/rcp* command.
`find path -type f -size +10M -exec scp {} destination \;`
Note the **\;** at the end. Don't forget that!

Option 2 answer.
Tested this in csh &*bash* 
`ls -rt [path]/[file_wildcard] | sed '$d' | xargs -i rm -f {}`

Comment: I actually think option 2 is the one I'm looking for. As I guess there will be a overlap where the latest file reach 10MB but aren't quite finished yet.

Comment: With logrotate, it will instantaneously terminate the active file and create the new file. What shell are you using? I'll see if I can get an option 2 answer.

Comment: Edited answer for Option 2.

Answer (score 0):

For files named as your example, this code will allow you to perform any action on all but the most recent one -- be careful though because in just a random group of files it would possibly match more than just the last one.

```
for file in `ls | grep -v \`ls -ltr | tail -1 | awk '{ print $9 }'\``; do  echo $file; 
done
```

This example just prints the names out; replace echo $file with rsync command.

Test:

```
[pt@NDC1ASCEM2DES1 test]$ ll
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 pt868x sysadmin 0 Feb 20 17:00 trace_00005_20190207154446.pcap
-rw-r--r-- 1 pt868x sysadmin 0 Feb 20 17:00 trace_00003_20190207134624.pcap
-rw-r--r-- 1 pt868x sysadmin 0 Feb 20 17:01 trace_00004_20190207144533.pcap
[pt@NDC1ASCEM2DES1 test]$ for file in `ls | grep -v \`ls -ltr | tail -1 | awk '{ print $9 }'\``; do  echo $file; done
trace_00003_20190207134624.pcap
trace_00005_20190207154446.pcap
[pt@NDC1ASCEM2DES1 test]$ for file in `ls | grep -v \`ls -ltr | tail -1 | awk '{ print $9 }'\``; do  rsync  $file NDC1ASCEM2DES2:$file; done
pt@ndc1ascem2des2's password:
pt@ndc1ascem2des2's password:
[pt@NDC1ASCEM2DES1 test]$ ssh ndc1ascem2des2 "ls"
pt@ndc1ascem2des2's password:
trace_00003_20190207134624.pcap
trace_00005_20190207154446.pcap
```